# Textured Overlays

Tags: png, texture

Is it possible to create an textured translucent PNG?  I'm attempting to separate the texture from the color - allowing me to define the color, ultimately, via my CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

What you might want to do in photoshop ( or other programs ):

- Make a new layer where you fill a color or possible color. ( This is so you know what it looks like with color under it. )
- Make a new layer on top of that where you make the transparent texture. ( I filled this layer with random grey color that i filled with noise and reduced the opacity to 14% )
- Hide all extra layers to get empty background for the texture ( Most likely Background layer and possibly extra color layer. )
- Once that is done Save for web as a png.

<sub>Limiting factor here is Blend modes which you can't really use extensively in this case, opacity and extra coloring can make up for that though.</sub>

Here's an example of it http://jsfiddle.net/y7SLu/

The texture image:

[image]